# How to use APK source code in eclipse. (Modifyin and editing)

Tags: java, eclipse, apk, reverse-engineering

I want to analyze apk source code in eclipse project. I am using apktojava program to get eclipse project. But when I import project as a android project, it has errors in all classes. Most of the problems show up because of missing .class files. How can I get this .class files.  I just want to see eclipse project without error. I get the source code of apk, then what?

Comment: try once importing it as a general project ,not as an android project

Comment: by the way have you configured your eclipse properly for android projects ?

Comment: I tried general project but not working, normal android projects are working.

Comment: if your dont have any issue with sharing your apk source code u can share

Comment: u can try also one more thing by checking which android version u r trying to test with (try with a lower version and increase thereafter )?moreover u can also share the errors u r getting